# Open source web-based disk space analyzer (to adapt it to my remote protocol)

Tags: open-source, web-apps, ftp, disk-analysis, webdav

There are tons of disk usage analyzer tools: [Baobab](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Baobab), [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/), [JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/), and [many](https://alternativeto.net/software/baobab/) [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Disk_usage_analysis_software).
They typically look like this:
[image: Baobab]

Now, I am looking for a **web-based** disk usage analyzer. For any remote protocol, for instance FTP, WebDAV, JCR or CMIS. For instance, it would show how space is being used on a remote FTP server (so it is not really "disk" in the hardware sense, more "repository").

My goal is to take the source code and adapt it to my own remote protocol (which is similar to WebDAV in concept, just using a different API syntax).

Requirements:

- Web-based
- Open source
- Shows a nice diagram showing where disk space is used (any shape is OK)
- Shows "Calculating..." or something similar while processing, as data is expected to be huge
- Either 100% browser-side (using HTTP requests to query folder from the server) or browser+gateway, the gateway making requests to the actual remote server
- Preferably written in a modern language like Rails/Play/Node.js/Java. So not [DUC](http://duc.zevv.nl/demo.cgi?x=481&y=326&path=/usr/share) which is written in C (and does not look/feel great)

Comment: Duc author here. Curious why you have bias against C? Duc is written in C for a number of good reasons: portability (runs on *nix, win32, macos, android, etc), performance (will not get any faster then this), lightweight, few dependencies, can be deployed on embedded systems. I agree about the bare bone looks, I'm not a designer. Feel free to style the CSS to your needs, of course.

Comment: @Zevv: Thanks making for this tool, while it is great for most people, my very particular case is that I want to fork the tool and adapt it to another protocol. So for very personal reasons it needs to be in a language that I have fun coding with, and that's why I expressed my requirement as "modern language". Sorry about the critic, I was mostly talking about the image where the blocks do not highlight when the mouse hovers them.

Answer (score 2):

I was currently looking for something similar and found **diskover**. Not sure if it checks all your recs (is docker container fits your gateway description?), but at least it's the best-looking thing I could find. But I wanted something simple, like treesize with a web ui, and this one has a lot going on, not sure if it'll be easy to adapt.

official page https://shirosaidev.github.io/diskover/

linuxserver.io image https://docs.linuxserver.io/images/docker-diskover

preview article (mentions important prerequisites) https://blog.linuxserver.io/2019/06/28/getting-started-with-diskover-in-docker/